# Open, read file and display text in spinner listener (java - android)

Tags: android

I want to display a string from a txt file using a spinner.
Or rather:

1) The user select from spinner a item (no problem at this)

2) The user visualize based on the position of the item within a certain thing (no problem at this)

3) The device open a file based on the item, then display it

Here's the code of "CustomOnItemSelectedListener" class, listener of the spinner. Can someone correct my code?

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
    if (pos==2)
    {

        BufferedReader br = null;


        try {

            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("napier_result.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

                TextView device_stat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device_stat);
                device_stat.setText("Your Device: " + sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Particularly on "findViewById", Android studio says "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)"

Comment: which issue are you facing? are you able to run your application?

Comment: @NovusMobile findViewById is the mayor problem, it says "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming TextView is part of your Spinner.
You need to use view to call it's element.

```
TextView device_stat = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.device_stat);
               device_stat.setText("Your Device: " + sCurrentLine);
```